# Conversion of height and width of object detected by yolo into centimeters

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I have trained AWS Recognition model on different strawberry classes. so, the problem is I want the size of strawberry in **(cm or mm)**
So I got a list like this when I run the AWS inference code
which is

```
def display_image(bucket,photo,response):
# Load image from S3 bucket
s3_connection = boto3.resource('s3')

s3_object = s3_connection.Object(bucket,photo)
s3_response = s3_object.get()

stream = io.BytesIO(s3_response['Body'].read())
image=Image.open(stream)

# Ready image to draw bounding boxes on it.
imgWidth, imgHeight = image.size
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# calculate and display bounding boxes for each detected custom label
print('Detected custom labels for ' + photo)
for customLabel in response['CustomLabels']:
    print('Label ' + str(customLabel['Name']))
    print('Confidence ' + str(customLabel['Confidence']))
    if 'Geometry' in customLabel:
        box = customLabel['Geometry']['BoundingBox']
        left = imgWidth * box['Left']
        top = imgHeight * box['Top']
        width = imgWidth * box['Width']
        height = imgHeight * box['Height']

        fnt = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 50)
        draw.text((left,top), customLabel['Name'], fill='#00d400', font=fnt)

        print('Left: ' + '{0:.0f}'.format(left))
        print('Top: ' + '{0:.0f}'.format(top))
        print('Label Width: ' + "{0:.0f}".format(width))
        print('Label Height: ' + "{0:.0f}".format(height))

        points = (
            (left,top),
            (left + width, top),
            (left + width, top + height),
            (left , top + height),
            (left, top))
        draw.line(points, fill='#00d400', width=5)
```

from this I got

> {"BoundingBox": {"Width": 0.04422999918460846, "Height": 0.07242000102996826, "Left": 0.3089900016784668, "Top": 0.6768199801445007 }

so I want to convert Width and Height into centimeters

is there any simple way?

Comment: Do you know the exact distance between camera and object? Do you have a reference object of know size at the same distance?

Comment: @Micka yes, I have both the distance of camera is 40cm and the size of reference object is around 27mm length and 25mm width. I only need the proper way to convert detection model readings into cm or mm.

Comment: If the reference object is at thr same distance, you can read the pixel width/height of the reference object and then you know the mm/pixel and can multiply it with your detected object box size.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is , but first, to convert from pixels to CM or even Inch , you must know how many pixels are in CM , To solve that you can use :

- Fixed distance Camera to do calibration and know how many Pixels in Cm.
- Or even you can use a reference like , the black square of any other to reference.

You can take a look [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpyimagesearch.com%2F2016%2F03%2F28%2Fmeasuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv%2F&psig=AOvVaw0tIi9XQIXcAsWPvGq2v-FI&ust=1685085715235000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBMQjhxqFwoTCNj04pCFkP8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE)

Another solution is by using 3D sensors you can use :

- Lidar.
- Any 3D camera.